# Working with Java 7 and Java 8 with two different applications at time is possible?

Tags: java, oracle

We have two different applications named Demantra (an Oracle application), and Kinaxis.

- Demantra works with Java 7 (only in IE browser) only.
- Kinaxis works with Java 7 and Java 8 (works with any of the browsers ).

Now my requirement is: when I open Demantra application, it must be opened with java7 only. In the same way when opening  Kinaxis application, it must be opened with Java 8 only.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Hy Tarun , go through this link https://support.inductiveautomation.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/87/0/running-multiple-versions-of-java-on-the-same-windows-machine

Comment: You could try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413358/change-java-version-used-by-java-applets-in-browser . No guarantees though.

Comment: What do you mean by "opening"? Double click on an icon on your desktop?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Java 7 and Java 8 first of all. Then you need to change the java path in the batch file(from where your application starts) of both the applications Demantra and Kinaxis. This should look something like `%JAVA6HOME%\bin\java..`